# Sails.js store a primary keys in postresql

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sails.js, waterline

I am trying to add setup a postgresql database while using the sails.js framework.

However, overtime I am trying to save some model values in my database, I've got the following error : `error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint`. Is there a way to store the id which is automatically created by waterline in a postgresql database ?

**/models/user.js**

```
module.exports = {
  connection: 'postgresqlServer',
  schema: true,

  attributes: {

    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      primaryKey: true
    },

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

---

**/config/connection.js**

```
module.exports.connections = {
  postgresqlServer: {
    adapter: 'sails-postgresql',
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'myprojectdb',
    socketPath: '/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.5',

    schema: true
  }
};
```

---

**config/models.js**

```
module.exports.models = {
  connection: 'sails-postgresql',
  migrate: 'alter'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `autoIncrement: true` for your `id` attribute.

BTW: Waterline automatically add `id` to every model. You can disable it with `autoPK: false` if you want.

Comment: I've done it and added to user.js the following lines :
id: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
    },

And have now this outcome : error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Comment: An what if, you just remove the id field from the list?